# Not getting expected values from JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to get JSON values using jQuery, but my code is not working as I expect it to. Can you please give me suggestion on how to fix it?

```
// JSON response:
[{
    "private": "8044553.0"
}, {
    "governmentdocs": "98952.0"
}, {
    "officialdocs": "5577356.0"
}]

$.each($.parseJSON(data), function(idx, obj) {
    privatedocs = obj.private;
    alert(obj.private);
    alert(obj.officialdocs);
    alert(obj.governmentdocs);
});
```

I am getting a value like `8044553.0`, then `undefined`, then `5577356.0`. Why is it showing like this?

Comment: The issue is because your JSON contains multiple objects, each with a different property. You need to make all the properties part of a single object, or change your logic to loop over them individually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have problem in your **JSON** : `[{"private":"8044553.0"}, {"governmentdocs":"98952.0"}, {"officialdocs":"5577356.0"}]` Your **JSON** should like :

```
'[{"private":"8044553.0", "governmentdocs":"98952.0", "officialdocs":"5577356.0"}]'
```

Here is the working example :

```js
var data ='[{"private":"8044553.0", "governmentdocs":"98952.0", "officialdocs":"5577356.0"}]';

                $.each($.parseJSON(data), function(idx, obj) {
                  
                        privatedocs=obj.private;
                    alert(obj.private);
                    alert(obj.officialdocs);
                    alert(obj.governmentdocs);
                });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thank for reply...@Bhavin ..Here i am getting Unexpected token ' showing

Comment: here i am getting json from servlet..as in this format  [{"private":"8044553.0"}, {"governmentdocs":"98952.0"}, {"officialdocs":"5577356.0"}]

Comment: after that i have added as per your concern alert(data);
      var jsondata="'"+data+"'";
      console.log(jsondata);
      $.each($.parseJSON(jsondata), function(idx, obj) {
       alert(obj.private);
       alert(obj.officialdocs);
       alert(obj.governmentdocs);
                });